# How to insert text with special characters and automatic line breaks

Tags: listings, lstlisting

I want to insert a Readme file into my latex code, which contains some special characters. First i tried to use a verbatim environment, but this did not work because there were no automatic line breaks for the code and some text in the readme is quite long. I then tried to use the lstlisting environment. But the text is centered and not left aligned. Here is a minimum working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{
breaklines=true
}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
# Title
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Any ideas how I can get this to be left aligned or any other ideas how I should insert the readme into the document?

Comment: for the code in the example you can just use `\ttfamily` and set it as a normal paragraph. what kind of "special characters" do you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
\lstset{
    breaklines=true,
    breakindent=0pt
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

\begin{flushleft}\obeylines\catcode`\#=12 %
# Title
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
\end{flushleft}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to use LuaLaTeX, there is `markdown`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{markdown}

\markdownSetup{
  rendererPrototypes={
    headingOne={\section*{#1}},
    headingTwo={\subsection*{#1}},
  },
}

\begin{document}

\begin{markdown}
# Title
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
\end{markdown}

\end{document}
```

[image]